# Different result in phpMyAdmin and php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, I am writing

```
SELECT `class` FROM `teachers` WHERE `var1`=3;
```

I can give results. The Results are 5,6,7,8,9,10. 
I am Trying this code in Sublimetext3. code is like this :

```
<tr>            
    <?php 

    $classlistdata  = $db->getrows("SELECT `class` FROM `teachers` WHERE `var1`=3; ");
    foreach ($classlistdata as $ndcld) {     

    ?>
    <td height="25" colspan="3" ><span class="admin"><?php  echo ($ndcld); ?></span></td>

    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

this code writing 6 times "array"
. How can I fix it. I am new PHP. thanks for your answer.

Comment: What is the array you're getting in result? `print_r($ndcld);` will show you all the items of that array

Comment: getrows could be used to return more than one column, so each row is probably an array of values with one item. Im not into PHP but in c# you would get it `ndcld["class"]`

Comment: btw, I wonder if this aint duplicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `echo $ndcld['class'];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whats behind the `getrows` method, but likely its just an normal SQL query since you get arrays. Well, in your case, `ndcld` is an array. An array containing all the queried attributes as an array key.

Change your code to:

```
$classlistdata  = $db->getrows("SELECT `class` FROM `teachers` WHERE `var1`=3; ");
foreach ($classlistdata as $ndcld) {     

?>
<td height="25" colspan="3" ><span class="admin"><?php echo $ndcld["class"]; ?></span></td>

<?php } ?>
```

That should do the job ;)

Comment: Stop duplicating answers. (also 'class' -/- "class", see SQL query)

Comment: @Kenyanke I'm okay with the `""` `''` part... but - dublicateing answers? Where? I was writing this answer while the other one was posted. Also, an answer here should actually contain some explanation. The other one doesn't provide any, even tho its a good answer.